# Select Pose Bones Per Script In Blender 2.8

Tags: python, scripting, rigging

Is there a new command for selecting bones when in pose mode?

```
myPoseBone = bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones["thigh.R"]
myPoseBone.select = True
```

does not seem to work (AttributeError: 'PoseBone' obejct has no attribute 'select').

However, everybody seems to do it that way. Does it still work for you?
Thanks in advance,

Matthias

Answer (score 5):

**Select the armature bone.**

Further to the answer by @yhoho a pose bone has a `bpy.types.PoseBone.bone` property pointing to its associated armature bone.

Example from python console (where `C = bpy.context`) , bone of interest has name "Bone", armature object has context.

*When unsure of things the python console is a handy way to interactively see what's what*

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Armature']

>>> pb = C.object.pose.bones.get("Bone")
>>> pb
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones["Bone"]
```

its associated armature bone, from its `bone` property

```
>>> pb.bone
bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones["Bone"]
```

Which tells us could also get this via the armature, *ie* the data part of the armature object.

```
>>> arm = C.object.data
>>> arm
bpy.data.armatures['Armature']

>>> bone = arm.bones.get("Bone")
>>> bone
bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones["Bone"]
```

The two bones referenced in different ways are equal

```
>>> bone == pb.bone
True
```

but are not an instance of same object,

```
>>> bone is pb.bone
False
```

A bone from the armature bones collection of type `bpy.types.Bone` has a `select` property, whereas a pose bone `bpy.types.PoseBone`  from an armature objects pose bone collection has not (AFAIK never has).

Hence as shown to select, can use either of

```
pb.bone.select = True
bone.select = True
```

The idea of using `collection.get(name)` is that it returns `None` if the named item does not exist and can be checked against `None` (boolean False)  and handled.

```
>>> pb = C.object.pose.bones.get("NonExistentBone")
>>> pb is None
True
```

Related

[Set active bone in pose mode from Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134250/set-active-bone-in-pose-mode-from-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

you need specify the "bone" method

```
myPoseBone = bpy.data.objects['metarig'].pose.bones["thigh.R"].bone
myPoseBone.select = True
```

Comment: Please add more information to your answer to prevent it from getting flagged as "low quality", and deleted.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 actually I thought the same but I don't know what other info add.

Comment: Consider changing up to `myPoseBone.bone.select = True` altering line above such that "My Pose Bone" is actually a pose bone, not an armature bone.