# How to move a bone in pose mode using python?

Tags: python

Knowing the names of the bone and the armature, I would like to animate the bone by setting the location and/or rotation of the bone starting from say frame 24 to 48. I'm an absolute beginner and I googled but I'm still confused.

I use this code to translate and rotate:

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 1, 0), orient_type='GLOBAL')

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, orient_axis='X', orient_type='GLOBAL')
```

They work only when I manually select the bone (by clicking it). so I tried to use this code to set the active bone but it didn't work:

```
bpy.data.objects["Armature"].data.bones["Bone"].select = True
```

Would you help me, please?

I enter Pose mode using this code:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pose bones belong to the object**

If `ob` is our armature object, `ob.type == 'ARMATURE'` the pose bones belong to `ob.pose.bones`.  The edit bones are in the armature `ob.data.bones`.

To set active pose bone(s) to use operators see [Set active bone in pose mode from Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134250/set-active-bone-in-pose-mode-from-python-script)

To get a specific pose bone knowing its name

```
name = "Bone"
pb = ob.pose.bones.get(name) # None if no bone named name
```

Once you have the pose bone can set its properties or matrix.

```
pb.location = (0, 0, 1)
```

[How to get world-space matrix of any pose bone?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/how-to-get-world-space-matrix-of-any-pose-bone)

Add keyframe for all locations x, y, z at frame 23

```
pb.keyframe_insert("location", frame=23)
```

Note if a bone is connected then translating will have no effect.