# How to activate a bone in pose mode with Python?

Tags: python, constraints

**summary**
How do I activate a bone in pose mode with Python?

**Specifically what I want to do**

1. I have many bones that have child of constraints.
2. During the process of setting characters, I often need to click Clear Inverse / Set Inverse buttons of those constraints one by one for all, so I want to write a script for batch processing.
3. Below is the code I wrote. I've got a list of bones I want to iterate over and the code for Clear Inverse and Set Inverse is also available, but I'm not sure how to activate the bones to apply the operation to.
   What code should I write on the commented line?

```py
import bpy
my_bone_list = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones
for i in my_bone_list : 
    # Activate the bone assigned to variable i from my_bone_list by the loop
    bpy.ops.constraint.childof_clear_inverse(constraint="Child Of", owner='BONE')
    bpy.ops.constraint.childof_set_inverse(constraint="Child Of", owner='BONE')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pretty well explained in [Set active bone in pose mode from Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134263/31447). `C.active_pose_bone` should do it right?

Comment: As far as I understand, what the link describes is actually select, not active. The bpy.ops code works for active bones, not selected bones. Therefore, I actually wrote and tested the code in the way suggested by the link, but did not get the correct result. Please tell me if there is something I misunderstood.